# how to initialize the redux form dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have edit form. I want to show the default value in redux-form. as I am new to react js. Please suggest me how can I implement.

```
const Editform = reduxForm({//redux form implement
  form: 'editUser',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: {

    mobile:'9008687282',
    company:'Autoplant'
  },

  fields: ['email','mobile','company']
});
```

I want in mobile to put the dynamic data which is coming from the backend.

```
const Editform = reduxForm({//redux form implement
  form: 'editUser',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: {

    mobile:'9008687282',
    company:'Autoplant'
  },

  fields: ['email','mobile','company']
});
```

Comment: Do you already have the data fetched?

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //console.log('state.edit.roles', state.userManagement);
  return {
    getEditUserList: state.EditUSer.getEditUserList,
   
  };
}

Comment: Better edit your question with adding all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

**EditForm** should be child component and you should wrap your parent component in form as well and then you can pass initialValues as props to your child. (You should do it if you have multiple components with same form aka Wizard)

```
// index.js
import EditFrom from './EditForm';

const App = () => <EditForm initialValues={/*put your initValues here*/} />

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'profile',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: {
    mobile:'9008687282',
    company:'Autoplant'
  },
  fields: ['email','mobile','company']
})(App);
```

Other approach is to initialize data directly in your **EditForm** using `this.props.initialize()` in your `componentDidMount`.
You probably should read some [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.1.0/examples/initializefromstate/)